# Implicit Conversion over a Collection

Tags: c#, linq, implicit-conversion

I ran into a problem this week regarding implicit conversions in C# on collections. While this (using `implicit`) may not be our final approach, I wanted to at least finish out the code to offer the team as an option. I boiled down the problem to the following sample case:

I have two classes in my example: one that represents a business object (Foo) and one that represents the client version (View Object) of this business item (FooVO), as defined below...

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Id {get; set;}

    public string BusinessInfo {get; set;}
}

public class FooVO
{
    public string Id {get; set;}

    public static implicit operator FooVO( Foo foo )
    {
        return new FooVO { Id = foo.Id };
    }
}
```

My problem is when I have a a List of Foo objects and want to convert them to a list of FooVO objects using my implicit operator.

```
List<Foo> foos = GetListOfBusinessFoos(); // Get business objects to convert
```

I tried

```
List<FooVO> fooVOs = foos; // ERROR
```

and

```
List<FooVO> fooVOs = (List<FooVO>) foos; // ERROR
```

and even

```
List<FooVO> fooVOs = foos.Select( x => x ); // ERROR
```

I know I can do this in a loop, but I was hoping for straightforward (LINQ?) way to convert the objects in one shot. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

*Edit* 
Fixed typo in example

Comment: Your implicit conversion to `FooVO` in that sample is actually returning a `Foo`, is that intentional?

Comment: @Chris Walsh - No, that was a typo. I will correct it. Thank you for catching it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A question much like this gets asked almost every day on SO.  You can't do this because doing so violates type safety:

```
List<Giraffe> g = new List<Giraffe>();
List<Animal> a = g; // Should this be legal?
a.Add(new Tiger()); // Nope; we just added a tiger to a list of giraffes.
```

In C# 4.0 you can implicitly convert from `IEnumerable<Giraffe>` to `IEnumerable<Animal>` because there is no "Add" method to screw things up. But you can never do a "covariant" conversion like that if the conversion of the element types is *user-defined*. It has to be a *reference* or *identity* conversion.

You'll need to create a second list and copy them over one at a time. Or use the LINQ helper methods like Select and ToList to do that work for you.

The name of the type system concept you want is "covariance"; a covariant relationship is one where you reason "Giraffes are animals therefore sequences of giraffes are sequences of animals". If this subject interests you then you can read about how we added covariance (and contravariance) to C# 4.0 here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/default.aspx

Start from the bottom.

Comment: Great example, Eric. Thank you.

Comment: OP never said FooVO was a subclass of Foo, so a.Add(new Tiger()) wouldn't compile. OP asked about 2 separate classes that need converted to each other. This situation comes up often in MVVM programming. I fetch a List<Customer> from my database and need to convert to a List<CustomerViewModel> for databinding to the view.

Comment: // Nope; we just added a tiger to a list of giraffes.
No you added a tiger to a list of animals, which is fine. I fail to see why this would break type safety.

Comment: @LHolleman: Values of reference types are **references**. Now is it clear?

Comment: It doesn't work when returning a List<Giraffe> from a function that has a return type of List<Animal>

Comment: Correct. You can put a turtle into a list of animals but not into a list of giraffes. Since the types admit different operations they are not compatible.

Answer (score 28):

The reason your examples don't work is because you are trying to assign an `IEnumerable<FooVO>` to a `List<FooVO>`.  The following should work.

```
 List<FooVO> fooVos = foos.Select<Foo,FooVO>(x => x).ToList();
```

Answer (score 12):

```
List<FooVO> d = new List<FooVO>(foos.Select(x => (FooVO)x));
```

Works for me.

Comment: Aha - casting inside the Select lambda. That works for me as well. Thank you.

Comment: That was the only way to get a cast to work from a .ToListAsync(). Thanks man!

Answer (score 10):

Use ConvertAll Method passing in the `static implicit operator FooVO( Foo foo )` as the argument

```
List<FooVO> fooVOs = foos.ConvertAll<FooVO>(FooVO.FooVO);
```

Comment: I get a compiler error with my above sample code and your suggestion. However, if I replace (FooVO.FooVO) with (x => x) it will work. I have not used ConvertAll<T>() before - thank you for the suggestion.